# How can i show all the objects of an Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

today I have been struggling to deal with a very simple problem.

I have in my system a model called Sensors and these sensors have_many :value_of_sensors

The value_of_sensors is like the history of each individual sensor, in order to do that i have created in the database a column called sensor_id which saves the id of the sensor

My Question is, every time i go to a specific sensor by going to the ("show") option in my application ( the url changes to sensors/8 ) which is the sensor with the id = 8 , how can i modify my code in the controller index of the value_of_sensor so it takes this id = 8 of the sensor out of the URL and display all the history(value_of_sensor attributes) of the sensor with id = 8.

For now i have tried to use this code in the controller index of value_of_sensor

```
@value_of_sensors = ValueOfSensor.where(:sensor_id => current_sensor.id)
```

but it seems that it does not work properly

Can you please help

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what doesn't work properly? Are you getting an error? Is there unexpected behaviour?

Comment: you could iterate on array `@sensor.value_of_sensors`

Comment: what doesnt work properly is this code that I provided, basically I am trying to identify if the sensor_id of the value_of_sensors is the same as the sensor.id that i selected. When i select a sensor by pressing the "show" button it redirects me to sensors/8 which is the specific sensor and now i am trying to get this 8 which is the sensor.id to match the :sensor_id of the value_of_sensors

Comment: Sorry if I cannot express correctly my problem but I am a new ruby on rails developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your clarification, it is possible you mean to do this:

```
@value_of_sensors = ValueOfSensor.where(:sensor_id => params[:id])
```

I am unclear where your `current_sensor` is coming from, however based on what you said, since you indicated this is the `show` page for the `Sensor` route, the id of the currently selected sensor should be given in the parameter map as simply `:id`.

As @taro said too, a much simpler approach is to utilize the `has_many` relationship. So instead of grabbing only the `ValueOfSensor` objects, you would instead obtain the `Sensor` object, and invoke the `.value_of_sensors` method. Example:

```
@sensor = Sensor.find(params[:id])
@value_of_sensors = @sensor.value_of_sensors
```